# React Router passing params to browserHistory from table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm implementing React Router to link from a table of search results to a separate Profile component upon click of any table row (each row would be a user/customer). Trying to format a table with `Link` is nightmarish, so I'm using `browserHistory.push()` within an `onClick` handler on each table row.

Problem: I need to render the Profile based on the unique row clicked and I've tried passing params to `browserHistory` with zero luck. Either the component isn't found or it just visits `/tools/customer-lookup/profile`.

**EDIT: Updated to add a handler function which then calls `browserHistory.push()`**

Router Setup:

```
<Provider store={Store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/tools/customer-lookup" component={CustomerLookupApp} />
        <Route path="/tools/customer-lookup/profile/:id" component={CustomerProfile} />
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

Table Rows: (without an `{ id }` being passed to `browserHistory.push()`)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.pushToUrl = this.pushToUrl.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    selectedRow: []
  };
};

render() {
    let tableData = this.props.data.map(customer => {
      return (
        <tr onClick={this.pushToUrl(`/tools/customer-lookup/profile/${customer.address}`)} id="customer-data-row">
          <td>{customer.firstname}</td>
          <td>{customer.lastname}</td>
          <td>{customer.birthdate}</td>
          <td>{customer.city}</td>
          <td>{customer.state}</td>
          <td>{customer.address}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

pushToUrl(url) {
    console.log(url);
  }
```

The `tr` `onClick` handler appears to be being called once for every row of data, which makes zero sense. Here are console.logs of the handler from `onClick`:

[image]

Comment: In your <tr> why don't you populate the push url with the id of the customer? `onClick={browserHistory.push(\`/tools/customer-lookup/profile/${customer.id}\`)}`

Comment: Well that just crashed my browser as it tried to visit every unique profile url for several thousand users...

Comment: My apologies. Modify that so that you have a handler where you pass the URL to a function that will execute when that is clicked. I'll post an example

Comment: Oh, I see. So you need to pass a reference to a function. You're actually calling that function when it loads which explains your behavior. There's a difference between `onClick={this.pushToUrl}` vs `onClick={this.pushToUrl()}` Note that in my example I  called `.bind()` to properly bind to the correct context and to appropriately pass the parameter but it will not execute until the user actually clicks.

Comment: That's interesting. I've been trying to make sure my bindings are up in the constructor method, but you're absolutely right. Works like a charm now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along these lines. Pass the url you intend to navigate to.

```
goTo(url) {
    browserHistory.push(url)
}

render() {
    let tableData = this.props.data.map(customer => {
      return (
        <tr onClick={this.goTo.bind(this, `/tools/customer-lookup/profile/${customer.id}`)} id="customer-data-row">
          <td>{customer.firstname}</td>
          <td>{customer.lastname}</td>
          <td>{customer.birthdate}</td>
          <td>{customer.city}</td>
          <td>{customer.state}</td>
          <td>{customer.address}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
```

Comment: No luck, still crashing the browser. It's interesting, because it's as if `browserHistory` is being called upon page load instead of when a table row is clicked. I see no indication of why that could be, though.

Comment: Hmm, that's bizarre. I just tried it with hashHistory and it worked. So despite you moving browserHistory.push() into a method, it's still executing? What does your code look like now?

Comment: Yes. It's as if the `onClick` handler is being set off upon the rendering of the table. I replaced the `browserHistory` method with a console.log. I'll post an image.